# Use AHK to close a specific PDF file open in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: autohotkey

Say I have multiple PDF files open in a single Adobe Acrobat window. I want to close one of these files. What would the AHK command be?

Comment: Send `Ctrl-W` to Acrobat ? How would AHK be of use here?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).